# Can the bitwise operators &, |, ^ be calculated from base-10?

Tags: binary, bitwise-operators

The bitwise shift operators can be calculated in base-10 by multiplying or floor dividing by a power of `2`. eg:

```
5 << 2 = 5 * 2 ** 2 = 20
7 >> 3 = 7 // 2 ** 3 = 0
```

Does anything similar hold for the `and`, `or` and `Xor` bitwise operators? For example, if I want to find `629` & `1309`, I could represent them in binary and the answer `21` (`0b10101`) would be fairly clear. But is it possible to calculate it without using binary in a way that doesn't involve decomposing both into sums of powers of two?

Comment: Note that your examples aren't really base-10 computations. Instead, they compute on the abstract integral numbers (which happen to be binary in your Python program).

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Mathematical_equivalents), the answer is "no": the only known mathematical representation of these operations involves "loops" (i.e. sums).